# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Rails Nginx config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Rails 6 app that I am trying to deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, but can't seem to get the nginx config right. Rails 6 adds a `/pack` route to load the webpacked assets. This is my nginx config (inside of `.ebextensions/03_nginx_conf.config`)

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      client_max_body_size 20M;
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/01_webapp.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      location /packs {
        alias /var/app/current/public/packs;
        gzip_static on;
        gzip on;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
      }

container_commands:
  01_reload_nginx:
    command: "service nginx reload"
```

The error I am receiving right now is

Command failed on instance. Return code: 6 Output: nginx: [emerg] "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/01_webapp.conf:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed.

**UPDATE**

When I change my nginx config to look like this

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      client_max_body_size 20M;
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/01_webapp.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      server {
        location /packs {
          alias /var/app/current/public/packs;
          gzip_static on;
          gzip on;
          expires max;
          add_header Cache-Control public;
        }
      }

container_commands:
  01_reload_nginx:
    command: "service nginx reload"
```

Then the default nginx test page takes over for my rails app... so confused!

Comment: Is it Amazon Linux 2 or 1 based EB platform?

Comment: @Marcin this is the exact version Puma with Ruby 2.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.11.8 -- I also updated my question above to include the full error message